# use of let in optional value along with if

Tags: swift

From the Swift book, that Apple has released we can make optional value by putting ? to a variable like

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil
```

and also written that “You can use if and let together to work with values that might be missing.”

```
var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
   greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

written above code for checking that optional value is nil or not, it will not go inside if optionalName is nil.

but same can be done without using the let like

```
if optionalName {
     greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName!)"
}
```

why in book it is suggested to use the let?

Comment: I've been wondering the same thing. While using the `if let` avoids having to unwrap (potentially multiple times) the value inside your `if` block, it still seems way shorter to avoid (1) having to include extra syntax, and (2) coming up with a new variable name for your optional, which in my experience is just turning `firstName` into `theFirstName` out of lack of creativity.

Comment: You’re getting fooled by the String interpolation’s ability to accept optionals. If the `optionalName` was used outside of that string, you would have to explicitly unwrap it with `optionalName!.useMeSomehow()`. Binding it with let, saves you that step inside the block.

Comment: you missed the '!' in your second code example. Should read: 
greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName!)"

Comment: let returns a Bool... so you only enter the block if the option stuff checks out... it is sugar

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your second code snippet is functionally equivalent to the one from the book. However, the book suggests using `let` to avoid multiple unwrapping of the optional value.

Since you are checking `optionalName` for being empty, it is safe to assume that you plan to use it inside the conditional block. When you do so, Swift would need to unwrap the optional value from `optionalName` again, because the variable remains optional.

When you do the assignment of `optionalName` to `name` in the `let` declaration, the `name` constant that you get back is *not* optional. This saves you the unwrap inside the `if` statement.

Comment: from your answer what i conclude is functionality wise it will always be same. But execution wise using let will be fast as it has to unwrap it only one time.

Comment: also will it effect the execution time if i use an optional string or an constant string?

Comment: @WildFire This is correct. The idea behind unwrapping the object once is to save time - a micro-optimization, for sure, but it may help in a tight loop, and may even improve readability.

Comment: not disagreeing here (just using words that look like i am disagreeing (: ) - I would image that some very minimal optimization would remove the need to do this (assuming idempotency), so I think it is really more about paradigm and sugar...

Comment: @GradyPlayer: That is a trivial optimization in a single-threaded scenario, but I'm not sure unwrapping a non-constant optional can be proven to be idempotent in practice since multiple threads might have access to it.

Comment: @Chuck if the variable doesn't have scope that would permit it to exist in another thread, then you should be able to prove idempotency.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion arises because you're using println to display optionalName, and println is smart enough to handle optional values and unwrap them as necessary.  If you used the hypothetically similar code:

```
if optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, " + optionalName
}
```

you would get an error because you can't concatenate a String and a String?  You have three ways around that

First, you can use conditional unwrapping after you do the check, but this is inefficient because if you reference optionalName more than once, since you have to unwrap it each time.

```
if optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, " + optionalName?
}
```

You can improve that by using forced unwrapping, since you've already done the test and know that optionalName can never be nil.  This is still inefficient if you reference optionalName multiple times, as each time the unwrapping must be done.

```
if optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, " + optionalName!
}
```

Lastly, you can use the if let syntax to test and unwrap all at the same time.  Name is safe to use because it will be of type String, not String?

```
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, " + name
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming from the ruby world where "Hello, (optionalName)" would return "Hello, ", i.e. if optionalName is nil then interpolate the empty string. Currently if optionalName is nil Swift prints "Hello, nil" and if it's not nil it prints something like "Hello, Optional("John")". When using "Hello, (optionalName!)" then it prints "Hello, John" and if optionalName is nil it causes a runtime error. For rubyist stumbling onto this wondering how to achieve ruby behaviour:

```
let EMPTY_STRING = ""
var greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName ? optionalName! : EMPTY_STRING)"
```